# Systemd-resolved not getting nameservers from DHCP

Tags: dns, dhcp, systemd-resolved

I'm running a few ubuntu 18.04 servers in a Windows AD environment. The servers have no problem getting IPs via DHCP, but the DNS settings specified in option-6 are not written to any files.

Originally, I just updated `/etc/resolv.conf`, but this config wouldn't hold after a reboot.  The standard 18.04 image uses NetPlan so we aren't concerned here about NetworkManager.  After tracing it back to systemd-resolved and having to hardset the nameservers in the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` things seem to be working.

My question is simply how does one rectify dhcpcd option-6 with systemd-resolved?  I don't want to have to hardset these variable on the creation of each server.

Also, dnsmasq doesn't seem to be an issue here, it's caching just fine as `/etc/resolv.conf` still points to 127.0.0.1 as long as `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` has the DNS settings.

Comment: I have seen a similar behavior in our environment where some clients do not get the DNS servers provided by DHCP when using systemd-resolved. Did you dig into deeper into this? For now I just unconfigure systemd-resolved but would be interested if you have found a better way.

Comment: I removed systemd-resolve and used NetworkManager to configure my DNS. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159084/make-dns-follow-configuration-from-network-manager-in-19-04/1159255#1159255