# Make DNS follow configuration from Network Manager in 19.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dhcp

I've installed 19.04 and removed dsnmasq, disabled systemd-resolve using

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

and want to use Network Manager to set manually my DNS servers. Now I want to configure a different DNS server, so I went to the network icon on the bar and clicked Wired -> Wired Settings -> Configure -> IPV4, select Automatic (DHCP) and disable DNS as automatic, putting my desired DNS servers. Even after rebooting, my /etc/resolv.conf file now only gets 127.0.0.53, not matter what I do on the Nettwork Manager configuration. Is there a way for the /etc/resolv.conf file to be configured by Network manager?

Comment: **Yes... sigh... quit disabling parts of your OS**. /etc/resolv.conf should show 127.0.0.53. make sure that the /etc/resolv.conf symlink is intact. reinstall dnsmasq-base. re-enable and start systemd-resolved. Use `resolvectl` or `systemd-resolve --status` to check your DNS configuration.

Comment: *Thanks, but no thanks*. I have a local DNS resolver that I want to use directly, without any caching by the OS. I don't want systemd to resolve DNS for me.

Comment: But... how do you expect your system to resolve ANY DNS when you disable the two services that do that?

Comment: Incredibly, removing both systemd-resolve and dnsmasq and configuring the DNS server with the old fashioned /etc/resolv.conf using Network Manager works as expected. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.

First, disable systemd-resolve:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

Remove the symlink for resolv.conf and create a file:

```
rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
touch /etc/resolv.conf
chmod a+rw /etc/resolv.conf
```

Now change the configuration file for Network Manager to restore the expected result: `vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
# add this line
dns=default
```

and leave the rest of the file as is. Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

and configure your preferred DNS servers. Done!

Comment: A more standard way to do this... without disabling services... or modifying the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink... is to edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf and change the `#DNS=` line...

Comment: And change to what, exactly? Can you provide some documentation about how this configuration would follow what is configured in NM? See, I don't want to hardcode DNS servers on files, I want to configure DNS per connection using NM.

Comment: `#DNS=` becomes `DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`. Change the DNS addresses to your own. Or do it as you suggest... individually via NM GUI.

Comment: Yeah, that's my point. I don't want to hardcode to some DNS because I'm configuring a laptop. When I'm in some places I want to use some specific DNS, when in others I want to use DHCP to provide DNS for me. If I hardcode the google DNS I'll be always using it. My solution seems to make it work the way I want it.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. If you put everything back the way it was... and configured DNS via the NM GUI... then using the `resolvectl` or `systemd-resolve --status` commands, you'd see that everything works as expected.

Comment: But as said before, I explicitly *don't want to use systemd-resolve* or any other form of DNS cache. Sorry to be blunt, but it was right into the question...

Comment: Then you edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.con` and change `#DNSStubListener=yes` to `DNSStubListener=no`.

Comment: fwiw I have the same use case as Ivan, and I have not been able to make `systemd-resolved` cohabit with `NetworkManager` by editing `resolved.conf` as suggested. Disabling the service works however.

Comment: dns=default in NetworkManager.conf is the correct solution.  Ubuntu does not need systemd-resolved, resolvconf, netplan.io, ifupdown, or any of the other unnecessary abstractions bundled with Networkmanager, which is heavy enough as it is.  I have absolutely no idea why they make it so complicated.